# Excel/ how to connect buttons on different worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

[image: my first button (Schaltfläche 83)]
my first button (Schaltfläche 83)

[image]
Other button which I want to activate vom "Hirata Bestellformular"
1st option: the top blue one 
2nd option: the big one (activexelement)

I want to activate one button from another worksheet because I want to execute the code below on the worksheet "Teileliste" directly from "Hirata Bestellformular". How can I accomplish this?

```
Sub Teileliste_generieren()
```

' advanced filter

```
Sheets("Hirata Bestellformular").Range("Tabelle3[[#Headers],[#Data]]"). _
    AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range("B50:B51"), _
    CopyToRange:=Range("B54:B55"), Unique:=False

    Range("B5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(LEFT(R[50]C,FIND(CHAR(10),R[50]C)-1),R[50]C)"
Range("B6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(LEFT(R[50]C,FIND(CHAR(10),R[50]C)-1),R[50]C)"
Range("B5:B6").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B5:B26"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("B5:B26").Select
Range("D22").Select
```

'formatierung tabelle

```
Range("B3").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 16763955
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Range("B4").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
    .Color = 16777215
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
End With
Range("B5").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 9868950
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Range("B6").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 15395562
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Range("B5:B6").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B5:B26"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("B5:B26").Select
Range("D20").Select
```

' Wenn 0 blank

```
Range("B5:B26").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
    Formula1:="=0"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Range("C22").Select

' Exportieren

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Teileliste").Copy

Application.GetSaveAsFilename

End Sub
```

Comment: There is a lot of code here, whilst it probably isn't all relevant to your question. Please reduce the code to contain only the relevant parts.  Also please specify what button you want to use, and what code that button contains. If it activates a sub, then there is no need to click the button with a button, but just call the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can try. :)

If I understand you, you want to be able to press `Teileliste generieren` from `Hirata Bestellformular`. This means that you still want the button `Schaltfläche 83` do to the same thing as `Teileliste generieren`, but you don't want to switch sheets to press the button?

**Then** I believe your problem is in your `Range.Select` statements.

In Excels VBA Object Model, if you call `Range("B50:B51").Select` from the `Teileliste`-sheet, then it will automatically select that range in `Teileliste`-sheet. If do it from `Hirata Bestellformular`, then it will select `Range("B50:B51")` from `Hirata Bestellformular` instead.

**This means:** it *should* work if you change all your `Range("...").Select` to `Worksheets("Teileliste").Range("...").Select`

This has to do with the [Excel VBA Object Model.](https://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-object-model/%20%22Excel%20VBA%20Object%20Model)

I'm pretty sure that should do the trick but it depends on where your code is placed (within the specific sheets or in a Module). Try replacing the `Range.Selects` and see if it helps. :)

Comment: I answered your comment in another comment:)

Answer (score 0):

Just A quick hint:

You can right-click the button Schaltfläche 83 and assign a macro to it. So in your case you can just right-click -> assign macro -> choose

```
Teileliste_generieren()
```

If your code can deal with being called on different sheets, then it Will work.

//from My iPhone

Comment: well that's exactly the problem:/ my macro won't work from a different sheet. Do you have another hint how I can manage my problem?

Comment: My comment is too long so I will post it in an anser. :)

Comment: May you want the document so you have a better insight? If you give me our mail I can send it to you:) Of course just If its not much of a trouble for you and you dont mind it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Teileliste_generieren2()
```

' advanced filter

```
Sheets("Hirata Bestellformular").Range("Tabelle3[[#Headers],[#Data]]"). _
    AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Worksheets("Teileliste").Range("B50:B51"), _
    CopyToRange:=Worksheets("Teileliste").Range("B54:B55"), Unique:=False

    Worksheets("Teileliste").Range("B5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(LEFT(R[50]C,FIND(CHAR(10),R[50]C)-1),R[50]C)"
Worksheets("Teileliste").Range("B6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(LEFT(R[50]C,FIND(CHAR(10),R[50]C)-1),R[50]C)"
Worksheets("Teileliste").Range("B5:B6").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets("Teileliste").Range("B5:B26"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Worksheets("Teileliste").Range("B5:B26").Select
Worksheets("Teileliste").Range("D22").Select
```

'formatierung tabelle

```
    Worksheets("Teileliste").Range("B5").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Worksheets("Teileliste").Range("B6").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Worksheets("Teileliste").Range("B5:B6").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets("Teileliste").Range("B5:B26"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Worksheets("Teileliste").Range("B5:B26").Select
Worksheets("Teileliste").Range("C18").Select
```

' Wenn 0 blank

```
Worksheets("Teileliste").Range("B5:B26").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
    Formula1:="=0"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Worksheets("Teileliste").Range("C22").Select

' Exportieren

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Teileliste").Copy

Application.GetSaveAsFilename
```

End Sub

I just replaced it everywhere like you said and it works if I aktivate the makro from "Teileliste" but there s error when I acctivate it from "Hiraa Bestellformular" saying: Error1004 he Select- Method of the Range-Object could not be executed:/ Another suggestion?:)